# Perl Mysql - How to search for specific data based on one "main" match?

Tags: mysql, perl

```
User Form Input - City
User Form Input - Venue
User Form Input - Cover
User Form Input - Time
User Form Input - Date
User Form Input - Number1
User Form Input - Number2
```

(if any are blank they are coverted to '*' on the way in. But could be whatever works.)

```
my $grabgig = $hookup->prepare(qq{SELECT `VenueNumber`,`Venue`,`CoverCharge`,`SetLength`,`City`,`Owner`,`Date`,`Time`,`Image1`,`Number`

     FROM `gigs` 
     WHERE VenueNumber > ? AND `City` = ? AND `Venue` = ? AND `CoverCharge` = ? 
       AND Date = ? AND `Number` > ? AND `Number` < ?  
       AND `Time` LIKE ? LIMIT ?,?});

##########################################

$grabgig->execute('100',$city,$venue,$cover,'*',$number1,$number2,?,'0','6') 
    or die "Did not execute";
```

That is a basic example above.

I want to be able to return results based on the City Input.

If more input is present, then narrow down results accordingly.

But the query returns nothing if fields are empty (*).

I tried wildcards and so on then, I experimented with LIKE and NOT LIKE.

This seemingly simple search is driving me nuts.

Can someone help this newbie?

Comment: You should really learn to format your code better.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say I understand what you're trying to do. Can you clarify "return results based on the City Input" and "If more input is present, then narrow down results accordingly"?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm pretty unsure what you mean, BUT, my best undererstanding of what you're trying to do is to query like you do now BUT if a particular field is not populated in the form, to avoid adding that field  to the `where` clause; as opposed to current query which instead does `and myField="*"`.

Correct?

If that's so, you need to build your query, and replacement list, in pieces:

```
my $sql = qq{SELECT MY_FIELD_LIST_TOO_LAZY_TO_TYPE FROM `gigs` WHERE 2=2};
my @replacement_values = (); # These go into execute() instead of "?"s
if ($city ne "*") {
    $sql .= qq[AND city = ?];
    push @replacement_values, $city;
}
if ($number1 ne "*") {
    $sql .= qq[AND number > ?];
    push @replacement_values, $number1;
}

# ... more values processed the same way

my $grabgig = $hookup->prepare($sql);
$grabgig->execute(@replacement_values) or die "Did not execute";
```

If you want to do it more intelligently (i.e. to generalize), you will have the form fields in a hash; have a config hash mapping the form field name to the DB column name and the operator, and instead do the above as:

```
my %fields = (
    city    => ["city"  , "="]
   ,number1 => ["number", ">"]
   ,number2 => ["number", "<"]
);
my $sql = qq{SELECT MY_FIELD_LIST_TOO_LAZY_TO_TYPE FROM `gigs` WHERE 2=2};
my @replacement_values = (); # These go into execute() instead of "?"s
foreach my $field (keys %form_data) {
    next unless exists $fields{$field};
    if ($form_data{$field} ne "*") {
       $sql .= qq[ AND $fields{$field}->[0] $fields{$field}->[1] ?];
       push @replacement_values, $form_data{$field};
    }
}
my $grabgig = $hookup->prepare($sql);
$grabgig->execute(@replacement_values) or die "Did not execute";
```

Comment: if nothing is present, you'll have WHERE with no where clause; I prefer using `push @where, "$fields{$field}...` in the loop and then `if (@where) { $sql .= ' WHERE ' . join(' AND ', @where) }` after; no need for $AND.

Comment: @ysth - yep. Shoulda just copied my standard code. The simplest solution (which my work code usually does) is prepending "2 = 2". FIxed

Comment: @ysth - I assume the last comment was MySQL specific. My work code is Sybase :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to construct a query where only a few input parameters have valid values and the rest are undefined. If that is indeed what you want, here is what you could do: Construct the query dynamically. Here are the steps you could take assuming you are using CGI.pm and assuming that the where clause is just a series of "this = that" - In your case you have different operators - but the idea is the same.

First construct a "where" string from the CGI query parameter (Sorry untested code):

```
my $qrystr = '';
foreach ($query->param) {
    if (my $val = $query->param($_)) {
        $qrystr .= "where $_ = " . $dbh->quote($val) . ' and  ';
    }
}
$qrystr .= "where 1 = 1";
```

Now you can just prepare and execute the query : "select * from table $qrystr"

If you want automatic quoting you will have to use bind parameters which is an easy extension of the code above

**Update** There was a missing "where" in the last true clause "1 = 1" - Sorry,  added it now

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, the formatting bar was not appearing so, I rebooted. Now I cannot edit my question or comment.

What I am trying to do is provide a search for the users.

They select a city from a dropdown then some optional data can be entered / selected to narrow the results.

The optional data May or May Not be present in the table, could be a blank field.

I would like the results to show based on the selected criteria of the search in that City.

So, WHERE selected "input city" = "tables city column" look for the other options (ignore that particular criteria if field is empty) and return any matches that exist for that city.

I am then pushing into array in a While for output display.

I guess it would be like a car query. Select make where doors = 2 and color = red and engine = hamsterwheel but, the color field may be empty in the database..

Comment: Dude, (1) the reason you can't comment or edit is because somehow you are now logged in with DIFFERENT account than the one you created the question with.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, if the user supplies "color=red" in the form, am I correct that you want to select out all cars that either have red color OR have NULL color?

Comment: Conversely, if the user didn't fill out the color (e.g. color in the form is "*"), do you want to select the cars of ALL colors?

Comment: I never created an account. I guess I should.. No, not if they ARE NULL but my query was crashing and I am a bit confused. This is very advanced for my level. Your example makes sense though, I an off to try...

Comment: @DVK Thank you... This is helping me a whole bunch. Could a moderator please check DVK as the accepted answer.

Comment: @DulcimerDude - thanks. If you wish, you can re-post the question under new ID (just register as a user this time) with your clarifications, and I'll flag this one for moderator to delete; and then re-post my asnwer on the new one.